# Stat function always returns -1 on valid paths

Tags: c, tcp, http-headers

I'm trying to write a simple webserver using sockets in C. I want to check if the request url is just a directory or a file i.e. localhost:8080/docroot or localhost:8080/docroot/file.html.

That's why I wanted to use stat() and the ISDIR and ISREG macros. Unfortunately the stat function always returns -1. The request url itself is correct (in this example it is /docroot). I also tried adding a dot in front of it, but that didn't work either.

```
struct stat fileinfo;
char request_line[255];
char* request_method; // GET, POST etc.
char* request_path; // the url
strncpy(request_line, in, indexOf(in, '\n'));

request_method = strtok(request_line, " ");
request_path = strtok(NULL, " ");

// the actual thing
if (stat(request_path, &fileinfo) == -1) {
  printf("Invalid path: #%s#", request_path);
  throwError();
}
if (S_ISDIR(fileinfo.st_mode))
  renderDirectory(request_path, sockfd);
else if (S_ISREG(fileinfo.st_mode)) {
  transferFile(request_path, sockfd);
} 
else
  throwError("Fehler beim erkennen der Datei/des Pfades");
```

So as I said, the request_path returns the correct url which is /docroot. The directory exists inside of the cwd. Unfortunately the stat function returns -1 no matter what. Maybe it's just a stupid mistake of mine, but I can't seem to figure this out...

Edit: the output of the printf is:

```
#/docroot#
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: `/docroot` is an _absolute_ path. It is never relative to the current working directory. Use `docroot`.

Comment: Can you add the output of `printf("Invalid path: #%s#", request_path);` and the result of [`getcwd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) in your question ? As well as the actual location of the docroot directory in the file system (absolute path) ? Additionally, can you also get the value of `errno` right after the `stat` call ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Well no, the browser is passing a complete HTTP header where the first line is GET /docroot HTTP/1.1. And I'm just parsing the path from it :/  So it isn't relative with the slash?

Comment: Please [edit] your questions to add the requested information instead of answering in comments.

Comment: As said, no `/docroot` is absolute. Drop the `/` to make it relative.

Comment: @Blade : in HTTP parlance, that uri is relative to the root directory for your http server, but in file system parlance (which is what matters for the `stat` call), a leading `/` indicates an absolute directory - ie. relative to the root of the file system (as @PaulOgilvie mentioned).

Comment: Removing the slash always throws a segmentation fault error...even if I explicitely provide the path...Wtf?

Comment: "*Removing the slash always throws a segmentation fault error.*" so then best **first** solve exactly this issue?

Comment: @Alk Great advice 10/10, would never have thought of solving an issue that just came up. That's purely genius. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue.
All of you who said it was because the path isn't relative: you were wrong. I have no idea why, but apparently a threading issue in some part of the code which is being called much later, was the problem here. I removed that bit and now it works with and without a dot and/or slash.

Comment: The comments might be wrong because you did not give sufficient information in your question, so the comments are based on interpretation and guessing. If you solve this problem by removing something in a different part of your code you might have (had) a serious problem like overwriting memory.

Comment: @Blade : if it now works with and without a leading `/`, that implies that your web server uses the file system root as http root directory. That is not a good idea, and potentially gives users access to your entire file system's contents (including password files, personal files, and other stuff that can be abused), and might even allow them to modify those files (creating further potential for abuse).

Comment: *All of you who said it was because the path isn't relative: you were wrong.* That level of demonstrable misunderstanding almost merits a downvote on both the question and the answer, if you mean that `/docroot` is not an absolute path.  If a path starts with `/`, it **IS** an absolute path.  Because either you don't understand what an absolute path is, or you're running your web server with `/` as the root http directory.  I'm not sure which is worse.

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Oh I see...Well, it's just meant to be a minimalistic simple server for a uni project, but I'm definitely gonna have a look at it! Maybe it will be important in future. Thanks alot for helping! Sadly, you're the only one here who's actually helping...